# What does "associative" exactly mean in "n-way set-associative cache"?

Tags: terminology, computer-architecture, cpu-cache, cache

I'm trying to grasp what does *associative* actually mean in *n-way set-associative cache*. I understand n-way set-associative cache as a concept; `n` is the degree of associativity, i.e., how many cache lines a set can hold.

If I take *associative* to mean "having the tendency to connect", I get to the "sets tend to connect to...", what, memory addresses?

But I'm not sure if this is the correct understanding.

Comment: It needn't have any literal meaning. It's just a name.

Comment: It seems *associate* here comes from *every memory location is associated with $n$ cache lines*.

Answer (score 4):

An n-way set associative cache is a cache that is chopped up in sections called sets. And each set can hold n-blocks.

A cache-address can be broken up up in 3 parts.

- the offset within the block
- the index that identifies the set
- the tag that identifies the block in the set.

When a request comes in, the index is calculated to identify the set. Then the tags of all blocks in the set are checked. And when a block with a matching tag is found, the right bytes are returned based on the offset.

A direct mapped cached is effectively a 1 way set associative cache.

So associativity doesn't mean the number of blocks the cache can hold, but the number of blocks a set within the cache can hold.

The big advantage of a n-way set associative cache compared to a direct mapped cache, is the latter can only have a single block for a set of addresses and the former can hold multiple blocks for a set of addresses.